How to figure out all dependencies that end up in the Next.js production bundle?
I need to list in component level all the dependencies that are included in Next.js production build. I've tried to do this with bundle analyzer but couldn't figure out if this data can be extracted from status.json.
In other words: if I list all the dependencies of a project with npm ls --all, how can I find out the components that made it to the production bundle?

Have you checked out @next/bundle-analyzer? It'll analyze the size of all modules that make it to your bundle.
